# How to make iphone app work in ipad with correct resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, screen-resolution

Hi i am new to IOS Development, i developed one app and tried to place it Apple store but it got rejected due to design issue raised in iPad resolution.I am using single Xib file in my design.please suggest me what can i do for to work my app in all devices like iPhone and iPad. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What was your exact reason for rejection?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html is something you should read before you start to develop .

Comment: Probably your app is iPhone only, but you have selected *Universal* in settings.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich I don't think so. The app wouldn't be rejected for iPad unless it was submitted as Universal.

Comment: @StudentT I mean currently app is designed for iPhone only but uploaded as Universal, thats why it was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

For universal app layout and asset management please check [this article](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-univeral-app-tutorial/).And also try to use storyboard rather than XIB approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the older XIB approach, it's likely that you'll need to create a XIB file for iPad and another XIB file for iPhone. I did it. It's annoying but it works for both platforms.